# Postgres: GRANT to user based on sub-query

Tags: postgresql

This is a symptom of database and user names being different between my dev/staging/live environments, but **is there a way to GRANT permissions to a user, determined by some kind of sub-query?**

Something like this (not valid syntax):

```sql
GRANT UPDATE (my_column) ON my_table TO (SELECT CASE current_database()
           WHEN 'account-dev' THEN 'c-app'
           WHEN 'account-staging' THEN 'x-app'
           WHEN 'account-live' THEN 'a-app'
           END);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `psql` and its wonderful `\gexec`:

```sql
SELECT format(
          'GRANT UPDATE (my_column) ON my_table TO %I;',
          CASE current_database()
             WHEN 'account-dev' THEN 'c-app'
             WHEN 'account-staging' THEN 'x-app'
             WHEN 'account-live' THEN 'a-app'
          END
       ) \gexec
```

Alternatively, you can write a `DO` statement that uses `EXECUTE` to execute a dynamic statement constructed as above.

Comment: Thanks, I used the `DO` / `EXECUTE` approach.

Comment: Could you add an example of the DO / EXECUTE statement?